# Bash скрипт из файла

Tags: bash, linux

Есть ли возможность писать Bash сценарии не в консоли Linux, а непосредственно в каких-либо исполняемых файлах, как это возможно в Windows, в батниках?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, есть:

```
> echo '#!/bin/sh\n echo "Hello world!"' > script.sh
> sh script.sh
Hello world!

> chmod +x script.sh
> ./script.sh
Hello world!
```

Расширение, конечно же, не важно. Бит исполнения - тоже по желанию (для него только шебанг (*shebang*) и пишется).