# Как правильно установить новую команду в командную оболочку (shell и другие)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Я написал, нашел в сети или получил по телепатической связи некоторый код для командной оболочки Unix (shell, zsh, bash, [и прочие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA)).

Теперь я хочу ее постоянно использовать. Как установить ее, так чтобы она была доступна в каждом экземпляре оболочки?

- Без подключения вручную на каждом запуске
- И даже после перезагрузки ОС

О создании установщика и пакетных менеджерах речь не идет, это вне темы этого вопроса.

В качестве примера предлагаю использовать команду, которая обменивает именами дв файла. В ней есть принимаемые параметры, но она достаточно проста для понимания и коротка.

```
mv -b $1 $2 && mv $2~ $1
```

**Формат: одна оболочка - один ответ. Оглавление я соберу в вопросе.**

Comment: В данный момент пишу ответ про zsh. Совершенно точно не напишу про PowerShell и cmd.exe, если можете - ответьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Связанный: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/132963/181472

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/360561/181472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в любой posix-совместимой операционной системе используется переменная окружения [`PATH`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html#tag_08_03).

поместите файл со скриптом в любой из каталогов, перечисленных в этой переменной (добавив файлу биты выполнимости) — и сможете вызывать этот скрипт по имени.

пример содержимого:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/bin
```

пример добавления битов выполнимости:

```
$ chmod +x file.with.script
```

пример копирования в, например, `/urs/local/bin` (понадобятся права суперпользователя):

```
$ cp file.with.script /usr/local/bin/
```

---

если нет прав записи ни в один из каталогов, перечисленных в `PATH`, можно добавить в неё любой другой каталог, в который у вас есть право записи.

например, `$HOME/bin`. если его (пока) не существует, то можно создать так:

```
$ mkdir $HOME/bin
```

добавить этот каталог в переменную PATH можно так:

```
$ export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

последнюю команду, чтобы не вводить её каждый раз после запуска *shell*-а, можно добавить в конец «конфигурационного» файла используемого вами *shell*-а, который находится в вашем домашнем каталоге и, скорее всего, носит имя `.shellrc`, где вместо слова `shell` надо подставить название программы, которую вы используете в качестве *shell*-а. узнать название этой программы можно, например, так:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
12450 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
12576 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

`bash` — этой и есть название используемой мною программы, а название «конфигурационного файла» в этом случае будет `.bashrc`.

Comment: Гораздо более фундаментальный ответ, чем у меня. Пожалуй, ваш я приму, а в дополнительных буду давать конкретные инструкции по пунктам.

Comment: мне кажется, спешить не стоит: кто-нибудь может написать ещё «более лучший» ответ.

Comment: Ну ладно, «расприму» обратно до поры.

Comment: более лучший ответ не случился, принимаю обратно )

Answer (score 2):

Конфигурация zsh осуществляется с помощью файла `.zshrc`, который находится в корневой директории пользователя (`/usr/username/.zshrc`)

Шелл-скрипт можно подключать несколькими способами:

## 1. Разместить непосредственно в `.zshrc`

#### 1.1 Через создание псевдонима (alias)

В `.zshrc` размещаем следующую строку:

```
alias swap='mv -b $1 $2 && mv $2~ $1'
```

Использование в командной оболочке:

```
swap file1.txt file2.txt
```

#### 1.2 Через функцию

В `.zshrc` размещаем строку `name() { <code>; }`. Если размещаем в одну строку, то последняя команда должна заканчиваться на `;`

```
swap() { 'mv -b $1 $2 && mv $2~ $1'; }
```

Использование в командной оболочке:

```
swap file1.txt file2.txt
```

## 2. Разместить в отдельном файле и подключить в `.zshrc`

Подключение сторонних скриптов осуществляется с помощью двух команд: `.` и `source`.

Код размещаем в отдельном файле в виде функции, `name() { <code>; }`:

**swap.sh:**

```
swap() { 
    'mv -b $1 $2 && mv $2~ $1';
}
```

В `.zshrc` размещаем следующую строку:

```
source path/to/swap.sh
```

Путь можно указывать абсолютный или относительно корневой директории пользователя.