# Где должен располагаться каталог tessdata для tesseract?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, tesseract

Все файлы переместил в /usr/local/share/tessdata/. Но после компиляции тестового кода в терминале возникает ошибка:

> Error opening data file data/tessdata/eng.traineddata
>   Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
>   Failed loading language 'eng'
>   Tesseract couldn't load any languages!

Я уже перемещал папку tessdata в data, но вывод аналогичен.

Материал по натройке брал [здесь](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling). Можно ли изменить путь к этим файлам или узнать в какую папку класть файлы? Пишу на Ubuntu 14.04.

Вот тестовый код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI tessApi;
    // тут data каталог в котором лежат файлы *.traineddata,
    tessApi.Init("data", "eng");
    // а rus указывает какой именно из них использовать
    if(argc > 1) {
        PIX *pix = pixRead(argv[1]);// считываем картинку из файла с именем,
        // переданным первым аргументом, это функционал Leptonica
        // говорим tesseract, что распознавать нужно эту картинку
        tessApi.SetImage(pix);
        char *text = tessApi.GetUTF8Text();//распознаём
        //---генерируем имя файла в который будет записан распознанный текст
        char *fileName = NULL;
        long prefixLength;
        const char* lastDotPosition = strrchr(argv[1], '.');
        if(lastDotPosition != NULL) {
            prefixLength = lastDotPosition - argv[1];
            fileName = new char[prefixLength + 5];
            strncpy(fileName, argv[1], prefixLength);
            strcpy(fileName + prefixLength, ".txt\0");
        } else {
            exit(1);
        }
        //---
        FILE *outF = fopen(fileName, "w");
        fprintf(outF, "%s", text);
        fclose(outF);
        //---
        pixDestroy(&pix);
        delete [] fileName;
        delete [] text;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Но после компиляции* — т.е., не во время компиляции, а при запуске программы?

Comment: Ну да, когда я запускаю программу

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: Я запустил програму по другому варианту, но надо что то указывать дальше. Вроде бы какой то путь

Comment: Я нашел файл `.bashrc` в папке home и добавил в строчку то что вы написали ниже, но толку никакого все равно пишет то же самое.

Comment: Уже создал путь `/usr/local/share/data/tessdata/` и распаковал туда все файлы но толку никакого.

Answer (score 2):

как оказалось, ошибка возникает не при компиляции, а при запуске программы. ответ немного изменён соответствующим образом.

---

> Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" dir

предлагают установить в переменной окружения `TESSDATA_PREFIX` родительский каталог для каталога `tessdata`. вероятно, подразумевается каталог `/usr/local/share/tessdata/`. родительским для него будет `/usr/local/share/`.

т.е., в текущем экземпляре оболочки выполните:

```
$ export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/local/share/
```

а затем (в этом же экземпляре) **запускайте вашу программу**. судя по:

> Error opening data file data/tessdata/eng.traineddata

этот префикс будет добавлен к `data/tessdata/eng.traineddata`, и данный файл у вас должен располагаться по адресу:

```
/usr/local/share/data/tessdata/eng.traineddata
```

---

другой вариант запуска программы (без предварительного экспортирования переменной окружения):

```
$ TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/local/share/ ваша-программа
```

---

для того, чтобы переменная TESSDATA_PREFIX всегда присутствовала в окружении ваших процессов, можно добавить строчку

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/local/share/
```

в конец «конфигурационного» файла используемой вами оболочки (инструкцию смотрите в конце [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/441642/178576)).

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял надо ввести TESSDATA_PREFIX а потом в терминале откомпилировать код. Но я использую Qt и как там сделать даже не представляю. Или это не влияет где компилировать?

Comment: вероятно, [так](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html#using-environment-variables) или [так](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html)

Comment: мне кажется проблема не здесь. Раньше я собирал исходник командами: `LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr/local/include ./configure`, а потом `make install` и программа выполнялась без проблем. Но собиралась с ошибками. Мне посоветовали использовать `./configure --with-extra-libraries="/usr/local/lib`, `make`, `sudo make install` После этого все скомпилировалось без лагов и даже тренер, но теперь появилась эта ошибка.

Comment: *теперь появилась эта ошибка* — так не перемещайте файлы (первое предложение вашего вопроса).

Comment: Ой, извините это я leptonica так собирал)

Comment: Удалил все деб пакеты tesseract, leptonica, а также сборки этих пакетов и собрал заново. экспортировал путь для tessdata но толку никакого. Посоветуйте что еще можна сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Ввел в баш (в моем случае MSYS2)

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/local/share/
```

Запустил обычное распознавание тессеракта

```
tesseract 3.png 'test' -l rus
```

Все заработало

Добавил по гайду с ссылки команду в конфигурационный файл баша - все работает без предварительной команды.

Ответ Александра помог мне при аналогичной проблеме. Полностью.